# can't find composer version after installing via npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I run

```
% npm install composer
```

I receive:

```
+ composer@4.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 901678 packages in 9.221s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 9 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

However, when I run:

```
% composer -v
```

I receive:

```
zsh: command not found: composer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **composer** vendor bin path manually in `.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

**OR**

make a **symlink** in the `/usr/local/bin`

**OR**

Please run this `brew install composer`

Comment: The first command didn't work, after restarting terminal. I'm not strong with the command line. How do I make a symlink in the `/usr/local/bin` please?

Comment: Please check this article to how to create symbolic link :- https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: So I use the command `ln -s $PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin /usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: Yes that is @Insight

Comment: Thanks. I did that command, restarted terminal, ran `composer -v` and still receive `zsh: command not found: composer`.

Comment: Can you run only ```composer``` @Insight

Comment: @Insight do you also run this command  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Thanks, `brew install composer` worked for me. `composer` now runs.